# nodejs and express with heroku im getting R10

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

thanks for taking time to help me

im deploying a nodejs express js project
these are the steps that i have done:

1- change the port to: process.env.PORT
code:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;
app.listen(PORT , function() {
    console.log('Application is listening on 9000');
});
```

2- create Procfile with: web: node server.js

3- make sure in package json the npm start command points to "node path/server.js"
the server works locally

4- important note: I am sending an AJAX request from my front end to the server to get data
I have read on you documentation that i should add 0.0.0.0

```
$.ajax({
    url: "0.0.0.0/hotels",
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(result) {
        bla bla ....
    }
});
```

also i have tried to add the url of heroku the one i get after creating

thanks in advance
have a great day

Comment: and what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: Eh, where did you read to add 0.0.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

did not solve it yet but i organized some helpful heroku commands

## useful commands

git remote -v
git remote rm heroku
heroku create
git push heroku master
heroku ps:scale web=1
heroku open
heroku logs --tail
heroku run bash

Answer (score 0):

Your code there looks fine (except `0.0.0.0` -- just use a relative path like `/`). I would ensure you've actually pushed the changes you have there. If you run `heroku run bash`, do you see your Procfile? When you run `node server.js` in that environment, does it run successfully?

I've seen Heroku customers get stuck on an issue like this, when the reality is that the code they have locally wasn't properly sent to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @jmccartie thank you for replying but it still does not work 
could it be the static __dirname? im starting to question every part of the code :D

I changed the path and just to make sure i understood correctly
it used to be : "http://localhost:9000/data/hotels"
now is: "/data/hotels"

would you mind taking a look at my code? 
just double check the parts i mentioned 
https://github.com/hibaAkroush/herokuNode
i will name the files to make it easier for you

1- Procfile in the root

2- server in server/index.js line 24

3- the front end (where im sending an ajax get request) client/home.js line 6

4- packagejson line 10:     "start": "node server/index.js"

thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok i fixed it ... 
wohoo!
not sure which thing i made fixed it

but what i did was:

1- I moved the server to the root and of course changed the code a bit so it would still work than i tested it locally to make sure

2- pushed on github

3- added ./ to procfile so it became

web: node ./index.js
instead of web: node index.js

thanks everyone !